# Azure pipelines UI to accept parameters (like Jenkins)

Tags: jenkins, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Jenkins has a UI concept with dropdown lists, etc. to allow users to specify variables at run time.  This has proven essential in our builds to make decisions in the pipeline (ie. which agent to run on, code base to choose, etc).  By allowing parameters we are able to have a single pipeline/definition handle the same task for many clients/releases/environments.

I have been watching many people over the past year ask for this - to eliminate the number of almost identical build definitions - is there a best practice to handle this?  Would be nice to have a single build definition for a specific task that can be smart enough to handle parameters.

Edit : example of possible pseudo-code to build on levi-lu@MSFT's suggestion.

```
parameters:
- name: ClientName
  displayName: Pool Image
  default: Select client
  values: powershell
  valuesScript : [
      assemble curl request to http://myUrl.com/Clients/GetAll
  ]

- name: TargetEnvironment
  displayName: Client Environment
  type: string
  values: powershell
  valuesScript: [
      assemble curl request using above parameter value to 
        https://myUrl.com/Clients/$(ClientName)/GetEnvironments
  ]


trigger: none

jobs:
- job: build
  displayName: Run pipeline job
  pool: 
    vmImage: windows-latest
  parameters:
    ClientName : $(ClientName)
    TargetEnvironment : $(TargetEnvironment)
  steps:
  - script: echo building $(Build.BuildNumber)
```

Answer (score 2):

Runtime parameters is available now. You can now set runtime parameters at the beginning of your pipepline YAML using `parameters`. For below example:

```
parameters:
- name: image
  displayName: Pool Image
  default: ubuntu-latest
  values:
  - windows-latest
  - vs2017-win2016
  - ubuntu-latest
  - ubuntu-16.04
  - macOS-latest
  - macOS-10.14
- name: test
  displayName: Run Tests?
  type: boolean
  default: false

trigger: none

jobs:
- job: build
  displayName: Build and Test
  pool: 
    vmImage: ${{ parameters.image }}
  steps:
  - script: echo building $(Build.BuildNumber)
  - ${{ if eq(parameters.test, true) }}:
    - script: echo "Running all the tests"
```

Above example is from Microsoft official document. Click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script) to learn more about runtime parameters.

When you run above Yaml pipeline, You will be able to select the parameter's value from the dropdown list. See below screenshot.

[image]

Update: To set variables dynamically at runtime.

You can use the `task.setvariable` logging command to set variables dynamically in scripts.

For below example: $resultValue is the value from rest api call. And its value is assigned to variable `VariableName`

```
- powershell: |
    $resultValue = call from Rest API
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=VariableName]$resultValue"
```

Check document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-scripts) for more information.

Comment: Very cool.  Any way to make it dynamic?  Based on a text file, or results from a REST api result?  Can it be based on ps1 script results?

Comment: Hi@John Hemnesey  you can use the `task.setvariable` logging command to set variables dynamically in scripts. Please see above update

Comment: Setting the variables isn't the issue, it's collecting them just before runtime.  So, you are close - but what this really needs is to run a powershell as part of the parameter definition - to make it dynamic vs. a static list.  Also it needs to have access to other parameter values [to make them cascade].

Comment: I put some psuedo-code in above as an example of what would be great.  We aren't necessarily using the release pipeline/yaml to release code, we also use it to run remote commands on our servers.  This gives our internal users the ability to perform all sorts of actions on remote servers without being given RDP permissions while doing their job.  It's a self-service setup, gets me out of pushing buttons for them.

Comment: I am afraid running powershell script in the parameter definition is not supported in azure devops. Currently you have to hardcode the static list value for the parameter. You can [submit a feature](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) (Click suggest a feature and choose Azure devops)request to Micrsoft development. Hope they will consider implementing this feature.